# Access the nested value in JSON without looping through it

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON, I want to directly get the zipCodes values from the JSON without looping through the JSON. How can I do it?

```
countries:[
             {
               name:'India',
               states:[{
                           name:'Orissa',
                           cities:[{
                                      name:'Sambalpur',
                                      zipCodes:{'768019','768020'}
                                  }]
                      }]
             }
             ]
```

Comment: You can't. Unless you already know the position within the arrays. Assuming you've just shown a sample and your real data has many countries, each with many states and cities?

Comment: @vihan1086 - Well yes, but the "funky tricks" really aren't going to be any better than looping through it, are they? I mean, you could for example use a regex on the (unparsed) JSON, but why would you?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes , so there is a lot of data to traverse , I wanted to know if there is any efficient way to do it .

Comment: @vihan1086 i need to populate an array with all zipCodes of a particular country , so looping through it and storing is not a good option .

Comment: @user1502144 I've added my solution, tell me if that works :)

Comment: The line with "zipCodes" is a syntax error. Those shouldn't be curly brackets otherwise that's invalid JSON.

Comment: Accessing an unknown number of values of a list without some form of iteration is impossible. That would require that you can access and process multiple values simultaneously in the same thread. Have you ever tried to listen to multiple songs on a CD at the same time?

Comment: If you're saying "I need to do <x> with <y>" where <y> is the obvious solution, it might help to explain why that's the case.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah but JavaScript is a higher-level language so it's looping might take longer

Comment: @vihan1086: Longer than what? How is that an argument to not use a loop?

Comment: @FelixKling longer as in time. Not saying looping is the wrong way to go but my point was is lower-level languages are "faster"ish.

Comment: @vihan1086: I don't see how the performance characteristics of other languages is relevant here. I could also say that Python loops are much more powerful, but that wouldn't be relevant either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
countries[0].states[0].cities[0].zipCodes
```

Please note, this works for the above JSON as there is only 1 country in countries array and same as for states and cities. However, if there are more than 1 country, state or city then, you will have to iterate to extract information until and unless you know the exact index.

Comment: this is just a sample data , the real JSON is very big , each country wil have multiple state , city and zipCodes , I want to get all the zipcodes of a particular country .

Answer (score 1):

As this is not an associative array, your option is only to use indexes like this:

```
countries[x].states[y].cities[0].zipCodes
```

Where `x` would be each representation of state in your array, in case, of course, that you have more than one.

Similarly `y` would be each state in each state in each country, in case you have more of those and you can do the same for cities if you need to.

EDIT:
Here's how you can iterate the array:

```
for(var c in countries)
{
     var name = countries[c].name;
     if (name === "CountryIAmLookingFor")
     {
         var statesList = countries[c].states;
         for (var s in statesList)
         {
             var stateName = statesList[s].name;
             .....
         }
     }
}
```

You can keep iterating until you find the country, state, and city you need, then extract the `zipCodes` from there as shown in the previous code snippet.

Comment: this is just a sample data , the real JSON is very big , each country wil have multiple state , city and zipCodes , I want to get all the zipcodes of a particular country .

Comment: As stated above, you will then have to iterate and check each value until you find what you are looking for. You can substitute X with integer for each item that you array contains and check on each step if countries[x].name is equal to the name of the country you are searching for and then do the same for states and city until you get to the level of detail that you need and extract the zipCodes from there. Does this make sense?

Comment: I've edited the answer above to include iteration loops so you can find the data you need going through the whole array.

Comment: @mmvsbg Unfiltered `for in` loops are dangerous ;)

Comment: @vihan1086 So is using regular expressions to extract JSON data :)

Answer (score 1):

## Without "looping"

You can do this crazy trick *(not saying this is the best way, but this way you aren't looping through the JSON)*:

```
var myData = { 'Put Your Data': 'HERE' };
function getCodes(name, data) {
    var sv = data.match(new RegExp(name+'([\\S\\s]*?}][\\S\\s]*?}])'))[1].match(/zipCodes":\[(.*?)\]/g), r = [];
    sv.forEach(function (item) {
        item.match(/\d+/g).forEach(function (sub) {
            r.push(+sub);
        });
    });
    return r;
}
getCodes('India', JSON.stringify(myData));
```

If your data is already  string, then you don't need the `JSON.stringify`. The `forEach` you see isn't actually "looping" through the JSON. It's already extracted the zip codes and the code just adds the zip codes to the array. . This line:

```
var sv = JSON.stringify(data).match(new RegExp(name+'([\\S\\s]*?}][\\S\\s]*?}])'))[1].match(/zipCodes":\[(.*?)\]/g), r = [];
```

is what grabs the zip codes, it gets something like:

```
["zipCodes":["768019","768020"]"]
```

The next line:

```
item.match(/\d+/g)
```

will grab the numbers outputting something like:

```
["768019", "768020"]
```

The loop just adds the zip-codes to another array

## With looping

You're better off looping through the JSON:

```
var myData = {}, // Your data
    zips   = [];

myData.countries.forEach(function(i) {
    if (i.name === 'India') {
        i.states.forEach(function(j) {
            j.cities.forEach(function(l) {
                l.zipCodes.forEach(function(m) {
                    zips.push(m);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});

//use "zips" array
```

---

## PERFORMANCE AND SPEED TESTS

After testing **copying an array** about **500MB** (half a gig) took about **30 seconds**. That's a lot. Considering an extremely large JSON would be about ~5MB, looping through a little over **5MB** of JSON takes about **0.14 seconds**. You should never worry about speed.

Comment: Unless OP is referring to JSON in string form, this is an inefficent answer. `JSON.stringify` is a lot more expensive than "looping through the JSON".

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I realize that, and I mentioned that it probably isn't very good and that it is a "trick". Question was to access the nested value without looping and that's exactly what I did. My answer answers the question and preforms perfectly for the OP's case, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: If you're just looking for an inefficent "trick" you could just grab the values from the function that's the second argument to `JSON.stringify` and if the key is equal to "zipCodes", push the value onto an array.

Comment: Change the `forEach` calls to actual for loops which are significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my "trick" for avoiding explicit iteration. Let `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` do the work for you. If your JSON is in string form, try this:

```
var array = [];

JSON.parse(jsonString, function (key, value) {
    if (key === "zipCodes") {
        array = array.concat(value);
    }

    return value;
});

console.log(array); // all your zipCodes
```

Comment: This will return an array like: `[["768019", "768020"], [...]]`

Comment: @vihan1086 flattened it

Comment: [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Json is like

```
countries =[
             {
               name:'India',
               states:[{
                           name:'Orissa',
                           cities:[{
                                      name:'Sambalpur',
                                      zipCodes:768019768020
                                  }]
                      },{
                           name:'mumbai',
                           cities:[{
                                      name:'rea',
                                      zipCodes:324243
                                  }]
                      }]
             }
      ]
```

So now we use MAP it will give you ZipCode of every cities

```
countries.map(function(s){
   s.states.map(function(c){
      c.cities.map(function(z){
         console.log(z.zipCodes)

      })
    })
})
```

**OR**

If you use return statement then it will give you 2 array with two zip code as per over JSON

```
var finalOP = countries.map(function(s){
   var Stalist = s.states.map(function(c){
      var zip = c.cities.map(function(z){

         return z.zipCodes
      })
      return zip
    })
     return Stalist 
})

console.log(finalOP)
```